# Aws Rekognition takes too long to compare face between 2 pictures

Tags: android, amazon-rekognition

I am using the following code for Rekognition.

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(xx, yy);
            AmazonRekognition rekognitionClient = new AmazonRekognitionClient(credentials);
            rekognitionClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));
            CompareFacesRequest request = new CompareFacesRequest()
                    .withSourceImage(new Image().withBytes(byteBufferSrc))
                    .withTargetImage(new Image().withBytes(byteBufferDest)).withSimilarityThreshold(90f);
            CompareFacesResult response = rekognitionClient.compareFaces(request);
            boolean matched = false;
            for (CompareFacesMatch singleMatch : response.getFaceMatches()) {
                if (singleMatch.getSimilarity() >= 90f) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
```

It is taking almost 1 min to finish the face detection between the 2 images.
Is this normal? I find it excessive so I am wondering if there is a way to speed it up or if I am doing anything wrong
Thank you

Comment: It might be the AWS Region where you select.

Comment: Is there a specific region I have to select ? I just chose that randomly

Comment: Same here (.NET API, correct region, images stored in S3). It is worse for me, request ends with timeout.